# Multiple text fields in single div with jQuery dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Using the jQuery code from [here](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/), but I am trying to have multiple text inputs in each div. It displays correctly and increments and saves the name and id for the first element, but for the second age input, it only stores the first input.

```
 <html>
    <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

                $('#input' + num).remove();
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what my new form and jQuery code looks like.

```
<form id="myForm">
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
    Age: <input type="text" name="age1" id="age1" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
</div>
```

```
newElem.children(':first')
             .attr('id', 'age' + newNum)
            .attr('name', 'age' + newNum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script only updates the first input, you need to loop through and update all inputs in the cloned div

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum = num + 1;

    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

    newElem.find(':input').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+/, newNum));
        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, newNum));
    });

    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');

    if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```