# Limits to multiple text fields in div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am incorporating code that I found on this site, for creating a dynamic form, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954384/multiple-text-fields-in-single-div-with-jquery-dynamic-form?rq=1).

However, I'm running into an issue where I am only able to add so many lines to the div before it causes errors on the page. Is there a way I can remedy this situation? Here's the entirety of the div I want to generate:

```
Server Name: <input type=”text” name=”ServerName”><br>
Operating System: <input type=”text” name=”OperatingSystem”><br>
Hardware: <input type=”text” name=”Hardware”><br>
Up Time: <input type=”text” name=”UpTime” size="1" maxlength="3"> day(s)<br>
<p>
HP System Management/Dell OpenManage/IBM: <input type=”text” name=”HPSystemManagementDellOpenManageIBM”><br>
<p>
Anti-Virus Software: <input type=”text” name=”Anti-VirusSoftware”><br>
 - Info Correct: <input type=”text” name=”InfoCorrect”><br>
 - Definitions: <input type=”text” name=”Definitions”><br>
 - Updates: <input type=”text” name=”Updates”><br>
 - TM Agents: <input type=”text” name=”TMAgents”><br>
 - TM Scan: <input type=”text” name=”TMScan”><br>
 - TM License: <input type=”text” name=”TMLicense”><br>
 - TM Version: <input type=”text” name=”TMVersion”><br>
<p>
Backup Software: <input type=”text” name=”BackupSoftware”><br>
 - Info Correct: <input type=”text” name=”InfoCorrect”><br>
 - Backups: <input type=”text” name=”Backups”><br>
 - Updates: <input type=”text” name=”Updates”><br>
<p>
Exchange: <input type=”text” name=”Exchange”><br>
 - Database Mounted: <input type=”text” name=”DatabaseMounted”><br>
 - Exchange Services running: <input type=”text” name=”ExchangeServicesrunning”><br>
<p>
Event Log: <input type=”text” name=”EventLog”><br>
<p>
Updates: <input type=”text” name=”Updates”><br>
<p>
--------------------------------------------------
<p>
```

The code I'm incorporating is below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

                $('#input' + num).remove();
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    </script>
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Edit:

Additionally, I would like to be able to have this div be an optional add-on that is hidden by default. It doesn't need to be repeated.

```
<div id="OMMaintenance">
OM Maintenance Notes: <input type=”text” name=”OMMaintenanceNotes”><br>
Up Time: <input type=”text” name=”OMUpTime” size="1" maxlength="3"> day(s)<br>
Event Log: <input type=”text” name=”OMEventLog”><br>
Updates: <input type=”text” name=”OMUpdates”><br>
</div>
```

Again, thanks.

Comment: What's the exact error you see?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.3? It's really outdated.

Comment: I'm just getting a generic error when I'm testing the code. Also, I'm a complete noob at this. I know next to nothing about jQuery.

Comment: Feel free to update it to the latest jQuery. Or show me how lol

Comment: What is a "generic error?"  Blue screen?  404?  Javascript error?  Is it browser specific?  When does the error happen?  On page load?  When you click on something? While someone may be able to figure out and reproduce your issue without this information, the general attitude on SO is that you've made some reasonable attempts on your own to debug.  At this point, you're basically saying "This doesn't work.  Please fix it." You haven't explained what you expect, what you've tried, exact error messages, or anything else that could help those trying to help you.

Comment: Well, I'm doing it at work. I was using a "Try it" environment from w3schools.com/. I can't really test it in any other way, for the moment.

Comment: The error happened on page load. I would generate the web page, in Chrome, and the page would just say "Error". Like I said, I'm a noob at this.

I explained I want to be able to show additional forms. When I click the button to show more forms, it does nothing.